# Is closed subset of $\Bbb R$ has least upper bound in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Closed subset of $\Bbb R$ has least upper bound in $\Bbb R$. Is this statement correct ? What about the set of all integers ? It is closed in $R$ but I don't see any least upper bound (or any upper bound for this set).

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is also a closed unbounded subset of itself. If you insist on a proper subset, a closed half-line to the positive reals like in MJD's answer works equally well.

Comment: I did mention $\Bbb R$ in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you observed, the set $\Bbb Z$ is closed but has no least upper bound.

Similarly, $[0,\infty)$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ with no upper bound, and therefore no least upper bound; $\Bbb R$ itself is also closed and has no upper bound.

Take any bounded open set $G\subset \Bbb R$. The complement of $G$ is an unbounded closed set and therefore has no least upper bound.